# How bind Checklistbox inside repeater control having datasource as LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

i my website i am using Repeater control which further contain checkboxlist control.

Now my problem is that i have successfully bind "Parameter Type" in repeater control but when i am binding checkbox values, it does't appears in display

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h4>
                    <%#Container.DataItem%></h4>
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkParList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                DataTextField = >
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                <br /><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <hr />
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

In *.cs file following are my code

```
IMonitoringDataInfo objMonitoringDataInfo = new ChannelFactory<IMonitoringDataInfo>("MonitoringDataInfo").CreateChannel();
                Collection<ParameterDetailDTO> clParameterDetailDTO = objMonitoringDataInfo.GetAllParameters(idList, out errorCode);

                var parameters = (from resx in clParameterDetailDTO
                                  select resx.ParameterType).Distinct();

                Repeater1.DataSource = parameters.ToList();
                Repeater1.DataBind();
                counter = Repeater1.Items.Count;
                while (i < counter - 1)
                {
                    foreach (var parType in parameters)
                    {

                    var items = from resx in clParameterDetailDTO
                                where resx.ParameterType.ToLower().Contains(parType.ToLower())
                                select new { resx.ParameterName, resx.ParameterID };  

                        ((CheckBoxList)(Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("chkParList"))).DataSource = items;
                        ((CheckBoxList)(Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("chkParList"))).DataTextField = "ParameterName";
                        ((CheckBoxList)(Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("chkParList"))).DataValueField = "ParameterID";
                        ((CheckBoxList)(Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("chkParList"))).DataBind();


                    }
                    i++;
                }
```

I am using LINQ as datasource

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

add OnItemDataBound event to Repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```

then in code behind do something like this :

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
       var parameters = (from resx in clParameterDetailDTO
                              select resx.ParameterType).Distinct();
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            CheckBoxList chkParList = (e.Item.FindControl("chkParList") as CheckBoxList);
            chkParList.DataSource = parameters.ToList();
            chkParList.DataTextField = "ParameterName";
            chkParList.DataValueField = "ParameterID";
            chkParList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your CheckBoxList binding inside the ItemDataBound event of the repeater.

See:

[Repeater.ItemDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx)

[Using OnItemDataBound with Repeater in ASP.NET and C#](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/repeater-onitemdatabound-cs.aspx)